# How to retrieve generated primary key when row was inserted with QSqlTableModel::insertRecord

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql, primary-key, qsqltablemodel

This question pertains to Qt 4.7.3 on Windows with Postgres.

I'm trying to insert a row into a pretty large table via `QSqlTableModel`, because this (hopefully) saves me the trouble of typing out the field names, by using  `QSqlTableModel::setTable`. I ask the model for a record object with `QSqlRecord row(QSqlTableModel::record);`, and fill this with data via the `QSqlRecord::setValue`. Here's the code to persist the row:

```
const bool insertOk = tableModel.insertRecord(-1, row);

if (!insertOk || !tableModel.submitAll()) {
  return -1;
}

QSqlError err = tableModel.lastError();
if (err.type() != QSqlError::NoError) {
  std::cerr << "errormsg " << std::endl;
  return -1;
}

const int primaryKey = tableModel.query().lastInsertId().toInt();
```

The above is what I tried, but the content of `tableModel.query()` is a giant select, with no `RETURNING` keyword. `lastInsertId()` returns an invalid `QVariant`. Is it possible to have Qt provide the generated primary key without making an additional - fugly - roundtrip to the database. I'd rather not lock the table to ensure the last is actually the one I created, if I can avoid it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" by using an additional query for `LASTVAL()`. Not sure if that's the correct way to use the Qt API. `LASTVAL()` is safe in transactions.